# Proving Bernoulli's inequality for $x>-2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, induction

For the generalization of Bernoulli's Inequality: $(1+x)^n \geq 1+nx$ I am having trouble finding out how to prove it for when $x \geq -2$ and $n$ is in $\mathbb{N}$.

I understand how to prove the inequality for the case when $x \geq -1$ but these methods don't hold for the above case. How would I prove this?

Comment: What makes you think it holds for $x \in (-2,-1)$?

Comment: @Macavity It does hold for integer $n\ge 1$ for $x\ge -2$.  I've posted a substantive "hint."  -Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^n-(1+nx)$.

Note that $f(-2)=2n-1-(-1)^n\ge 0$, and $f(-1)=n-1\ge 0$, for $n\ge 1$.

Furthermore, $f'(x)=n\left((1+x)^{n-1}-1\right) \le 0$ for $-2\le x\le -1$ and $n\ge 1$ and $f'(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in (-2,-1)$.

Comment: Your hint looks perfect +1, unless calculus is not yet in the OP's repertoire.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you!  Very much appreciative.  -Mark

Comment: very helpful, thanks